# Interpreting the value of pair correlation function

Tags: r, spatial

I'm attempting to learn various methods for summarizing spatial statistics, and I'm struggling to understand how to interpret the value of the pair correlation function.  [This link](http://wiki.landscapetoolbox.org/doku.php/spatial_analysis_methods:ripley_s_k_and_pair_correlation_function) gives a nice qualitative description of how the PCF is different from Ripley's K function, but it doesn't go into how the value itself can be informative.  The [documentation on pcf()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/pcf) from spatstat in R has some insight, telling me how to interpret $g(r)$ values above and below 1 (the value of $g(r)$ corresponding to CSR), but no more granularity than that.  My question: **How do I interpret the value of the pair correlation function?**

As some further context, here are two graphs of the PCF for two different species in a given observational area:

[image: Plot 1]

And a second species:
[image]

At a distance of 50 meters, Species 1 has a g(r) value of ~1.5 while Species 2 has a g(r) value of ~1.25.  **Can I infer anything about the two species from those values?** For example, is it appropriate to say that at 50m, Species 1 is 120% as dense as Species 2?

As always, many thanks for any assistance folks can provide.

*---Edit after further research---*
After reading some more, [particularly this, pg 620](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2745.2009.01510.x/pdf), it seems I can consider the $g(r)$ as a ratio of the density at a given distance to the total average density across the window of observation?  **Further, since CSR is $g_{poiss}(r)=1$, $g(r)$ is the ratio of density to a Poisson CSR?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remember that everything is related to *pairs* of points. So in your example at 50m it is more likely to observe pairs of species 1 separated by 50m than pairs of species 2 separated by 50m. For species 1 you could say that observing pairs separated by 50m is 1.5 times more likely for the process generating species 1 than complete spatial randomness with the same average density of points.

You can read more about the pair correlation function in [chapter 7](http://spatstat.github.io/book/sample-chapters/chapter07.pdf) of the book *Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R* I have recently co-authored with Adrian Baddeley and Rolf Turner.

Comment: Ah, fantastic.  Thank  you for your help and the link.  I'll read through that.